# How to create a clickable link in rebol VID?

Tags: rebol

Let's say I want to create a twitter client which list tweets. How would I create and detect a clickable link within a text zone ?

Update: I mean in rebol VID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a script that detects URLs in `face/text` and overlays hyperlinks: http://www.ross-gill.com/r/link-up.html

```
view layout [
    my-text: text read %some.txt
    do [link-up my-text]
]
```

It's based on the pattern in the article below, so you may need to adapt the recognition pattern to your specifications.  The links are passed through a `to-link` function which by default is the same as `to-url`

- http://www.ross-gill.com/page/Beyond_Regular_Expressions

Comment: There are some limitations for sure, but it works as well as many others - for example, certain iPhone Twitter clients I've used...

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you want to:

- parse your string to identify **URLs**
- replace each URL with an **anchor tag**

REBOL.org uses code very similar to the code below to do that. Note there are three elements to the implementation:

1. a set of parse definitions that define a URL and its components
2. a function that parses a string. Each time it finds a URL in the string, it calls an external function. It replaces the original string's URL with whatever that external function returns to it
3. an external function that simply wraps a URL in an anchor tag

   ```
   ;;   ======================================
   ;;   Definitions provided by
   ;;   Andrew Martin, 15-June-2004
   ;;   ....not all are needed for locating URLs ... so
   ;;   feel free to remove unnecessary items

   Octet: charset [#"^(00)" - #"^(FF)"]
   Digit: charset "0123456789"
   Digits: [some Digit]
   Upper: charset [#"A" - #"Z"]
   Lower: charset [#"a" - #"z"]
   Alpha: union Upper Lower
   Alphas: [some Alpha]
   AlphaDigit: union Alpha Digit
   AlphaDigits: [some AlphaDigit]
   Hex: charset "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef"
   Char: union AlphaDigit charset "-_~+*'"
   Chars: [some [Char | Escape]]
   Escape: [#"%" Hex Hex]
   Path: union AlphaDigit charset "-_~+*'/.?=&;{}#"
   Domain-Label: Chars
   Domain: [Domain-Label any [#"." Domain-Label]]
   IP-Address: [Digits #"." Digits #"." Digits #"." Digits]
   User: [some [Char | Escape | #"."]]
   Host: [Domain | IP-Address]
   Email^: [User #"@" Host]
   Url^: [["http://" | "ftp://" | "https://"] some Path] 


   ;; function to locate URLs in a string
   ;; and call an action func when each is found
   ;; ==========================================

   find-urls:  func [
       String [string!]
       action-func [function!]
      /local Start Stop
    ][
     parse/all String [
        any [
           Start: copy url url^  Stop: (
              Stop: change/part Start action-func url Stop
              print start 
              )
              thru </a>    ;; this is dependent on the action-func setting </a> as an end marker
           | skip
           ]
        end
        ]
       return String
         ]

       ;; example of usage with an action-func that
       ;; replaces url references with an anchor tag
       ;; ===========================================

   target-string: {this string has this url http://www.test.com/path in it
   and also this one: https://www.test.com/example.php}

   find-urls target-string
        func [url][print url return rejoin [{<a href="} url {">} url </a>]]
   probe target-string

    {this string has this url <a href="http://www.test.com/path">http://www.test.com/path</a> in it
    and also this one: <a href="https://www.test.com/example.php">https://www.test.com/example.php</a>}
   ```

**Notes**

1. You should easily be able to see how to adapt **find-urls** into, say, **find-email-addresses** for obfucation and/or clickability; all the parse definitions for finding email addresses are in the sample above
2. You can see REBOL.org's version of this code in operation here, for example: http://www.rebol.org/aga-display-posts.r?offset=0&post=r3wp157x17091
3. I'll leave you the exercise of bypassing making it clickable if the URL is already in an anchor tag
4. Also left out: any need to escape chars in the URL (eg & ==> amp;)
5. Thanks to REBOL pioneer **Andrew Martin** for the original code that this is based on.

Comment: Sorry I realized I wasn't clear in my question: I mean in Rebol VID box